# Sed replacing values from input file

Tags: sed

how can I import/replace(sed) these values from input file

```
cellIdentity="461"
cellIdentity="465"
cellIdentity="468"
cellIdentity="462"
cellIdentity="466"
cellIdentity="469"
cellIdentity="463"
cellIdentity="467"
cellIdentity="460"
```

. and put them to this file by order, replacing cellIdentity in the file below:

```
sectorNumber="1"

>


<Cell

cellNumber="1"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="461"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="2"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>


<Cell

cellNumber="2"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="465"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="2"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>


<Cell

cellNumber="3"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="468"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="1"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>

</Sector>


<Sector

sectorNumber="2"

>


<Cell

cellNumber="1"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="462"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="2"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>


<Cell

cellNumber="2"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="466"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="2"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>


<Cell

cellNumber="3"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="469"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="1"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>

</Sector>


<Sector

sectorNumber="3"

>


<Cell

cellNumber="1"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="463"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="2"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>


<Cell

cellNumber="2"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="467"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="2"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>


<Cell

cellNumber="3"

cellCreated="YES"

cellIdentity="460"

cellRange="35000"

baseBandPoolId="1"

numberOfTxBranches="1"

numberOfRxBranches="2"

/>

</Sector>
```

I'm new at this programing, so any help is appriciate.
I use /bin/csh.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They already look in order to me. But I am guessing you want to do something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$(NF-1);next}/cellIdentity/{$(NF-1)=a[++i]}1' FS='"' OFS='"' inputFile bigFile
```

Comment: Big file is output. Both are .xml. So in ouput basicly it's only "cellidentity" and they need to be changed with the values from input file. The command you send i got answer awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @user3319356 Instead of `awk` use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`.

Comment: thanks man, it's working:)...one more thing, if I'm not bodering you to much...for example, this Input file is greped from some biger text file, where I have this (cellidentities), but I need to add three more  lines  (same but with last digit diferent) in lines 3,6,9. For exapmle "cellIdentitiy= 4648", "4649", "4640"....so last digit's 48,49,40 are fixed allways, and need to be put in this order to line 3,6,9 :)

Answer (score 0):

Using awk (your input file is good format, you can replace the match line directly)

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next}/cellIdentity/{$0=a[++i]}1' input largefile
```